# openpyxl load_workbook TypeError:sequence item 2: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to transfer the data from one xlsx file to another xlsx file, so I write this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 

wb_source = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
wb_target = load_workbook('template.xlsx',keep_vba=True)
```

but seems second load doesn't work:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f9200c00961e> in <module>()
      2 
      3 wb_source = load_workbook('test.xlsx') #Get the current Active Sheet
----> 4 wb_target = load_workbook('template.xlsx',keep_vba=True)
      5 #based on sheet name
      6 #ws_source = wb_source.get_sheet_by_name("raw-74126")

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, use_iterators, keep_vba, guess_types, data_only)
    190         if strings_path.startswith("/"):
    191             strings_path = strings_path[1:]
--> 192         shared_strings = read_string_table(archive.read(strings_path))
    193     else:
    194         shared_strings = []

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\strings.py in read_string_table(xml_source)
     19         if node.tag == '{%s}si' % SHEET_MAIN_NS:
     20 
---> 21             text = Text.from_tree(node).content
     22             text = text.replace('x005F_', '')
     23             strings.append(text)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\text.py in content(self)
    183         for block in self.formatted:
    184             snippets.append(block.t)
--> 185         return "".join(snippets)

TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

The target one is I save as from a xlsm file, could you guys help me to see what happens?

Comment: Welcome to SO! See the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Which version of openpyxl are you using?

Comment: the version 2.3.2

Answer (score -1):

It is necessary to update module openpyxl to 2.4.2